# NullPointerException (when String is initialized)

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception

Following is a snippet that throws `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

```
else if(jRadioButton2.isSelected()) {
             // chrome selected
             String chrome_count_S="0";
             int chrome_count_I=0;
             FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("D:\\UnderTest\\MyFirstPoll\\build\\classes\\poll_count\\Chrome.txt");
             FileReader reader = new FileReader("D:\\UnderTest\\MyFirstPoll\\build\\classes\\poll_count\\Chrome.txt");
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
             while((chrome_count_S = br.readLine()) != null) {
                  chrome_count_I = Integer.parseInt(chrome_count_S);
                  chrome_count_I++;
                  chrome_count_S = Integer.toString(chrome_count_I);
             }
             writer.write(chrome_count_S);
             writer.close();
```

When this snippet is encountered `NullPointerException` is thrown.  If I replace the argument of `writer.write(chrome_count_S);` to `writer.write("chrome_count_S");` I.E. a `String`, I don't get any exception.  Otherwise why do I get the exception when I have initialized the string `chrome_count_S`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `while` loop stops when the `readline()` is `null` and writes the current value to the variable `chrome_count_S`.

```
while((chrome_count_S = br.readLine()) != null)
```

So `chrome_count_S` is be `null` after the loop and at the the `write` command.

=== UPDATE ===

Remove the `chrome_count_S` row in the loop and take the value from the `chrome_count_I` during writing:

```
while((chrome_count_S = br.readLine()) != null) {
    chrome_count_I = Integer.parseInt(chrome_count_S);
    chrome_count_I++;
}
writer.write(Integer.toString(chrome_count_I));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `while` loop doesn't exist *until* `chrome_count_S` is `null`. So of course the call to `writer.write()` will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

probably because before the `writer.write`, you have the while loop

`while((chrome_count_S = br.readLine()) != null)`

which ends only when `br.readline()` puts a `NULL` in the `chrome_count_S`

Answer (score 0):

Even though you initialized it, at some point br.readLine() assigns null to chroe_count_S.